# Detect if a fs writable stream is full

Tags: node.js

I'm opening a writable stream to a device (e.g: `/dev/disk2`) with `fs.createWriteStream()`. Assuming I don't know the device size in advance, how could I correctly detect if the device can't receive more data (e.g: the device doesn't have any more space)?

If I simulate such scenario, I eventually get an `EIO` error emitted from the stream:

```
Error: EIO: i/o error, write
  at Error (native) errno: -5, code: 'EIO', syscall: 'write', type: 'write'
```

But then an `EIO` is too generic, and can be thrown in other situations as well.

I'm inspecting the properties of the stream object once the error is thrown but there doesn't seem to exist a flag I could use to determine this.

Comment: stramsn are data flown based on events, are you listening for the error event? writer.on('error', err => { /*do something here and close the stream*/ });

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon Yes, and an `EIO` is emitted, which is not helpful. An `ENOSPC` seems more appropriate but its not the case.

Comment: can you verify the size of your source and dest before trying to write?